# how to post the json data to local json file using angularjs 2?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Am new to Angularjs2. Please let me anyone help to solve the issue.I get the json data from local json file when i update the form again it need to save and replace the old to new json file.Please help me.

Comment: You can't store/update data in json file dynamically/thorugh javascript

Comment: You cant make changes with script if you want to chang use some backends

Comment: Hello :) Could you please explain you problem in deeper detail? Perhaps show us some code so we can get a better understanding of your problem? Where does this json file come from and where does i need to go ?

Comment: Hi In my Ticket application filling large no.data .Once i POST the values it will store as "data/create/TKD12345.json".The JSON is saved locally and when i update the ticket the saved JSON will also update in locally.This is scenario.Please try to help in angular2 code@methgaard